# Printing numbers in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I'm working with this snowflake query

```
With N ( select 1 as number
            Union all
           Select number= number+1 
           from N where number <=35)
           Select * from N
```

When I run this query it was throwing error.

> Sql compilation error: type mismatch between anchor and recursive term of column number in recursive CTE N.

How to solve??

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL with wrong CTE syntax .
This will work

```
With N  as ( select 1 as number),      
     N as  ( Select number= number+1 from N where number <=35)            
Select * from N
```

But my question is what is you are trying to do here ? If you are looking for a series of numbers you can use `generator` function.

```
  select seq4() as rnum
  from table(generator(rowcount => 10)) v --generate 10 numbers
  order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for a recursive CTE to generate a gap-free sequence:

```
with N as
(
select 1 as NUM
union all
select NUM + 1 from N
where NUM < 35
)
select * from N
```

As Koushik mentioned, a sequence is preferable. The two use cases for something like a recursive CTE are:

1. Gap-free sequences. Snowflake sequences are not guaranteed to be gap free.
2. Dynamically calculated number of rows. The generator function requires a constant value for the number of rows.